# Kudan Camera issue from Unity 5.5 to iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, kudan

I know someone else had a question like this.
When I build to my iPad or iPhone the color on the camera(Background plane) Is green and pink. Is this a problem with the Background shader? when I apply the ycbcr material to the background plane in Kudan unity there is no change.

[Results with Unity Kudan Built to iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D5tn.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and got help from Kudan support.
Hope this helps.

I changed the YpCbCr shader with this.
•   Altering the mul function of the background shader to:

```
float3 ycbcr2rgb(float3 yuv)
{ 
    float b = 1.164 * (-0.0625 + yuv.r) + 1.596 * (-0.5 + yuv.g); 
    float g = 1.164 * (-0.0625 + yuv.r) - 0.392 * (-0.5 + yuv.b) - 0.813 * (-0.5 + yuv.g);
    float r = 1.164 * (-0.0625 + yuv.r) + 2.017 * (-0.5 + yuv.b);
    return float3(r, g, b);
```